# How can i correct the error i keep getting in creating a react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Each time i tried creating a react app using create-react-app <...name> i keep getting this error "
Creating a new React app in C:\windows\system32\brian-todos.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...tXcMskoaoOolrubJ3NQGh'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\BrianMartinez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-01-12T13_11_25_580Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting brian-todos / from C:\windows\system32
Done."

I even tried npm clear cache it still didn't not work.What do i do about this challenge

Answer (score 1):

It seems you opened your windows console or powershell as an administrator, and you landed in system32 folder. Don't create your project there, that is a reserved folder for system executables. Do something like `cd C:\Users\yourusername\Documents` and try there.

Comment: I didn't use my powershell as an administrator. Beside i just followed your instruction but still encountered the same problem. However, it is important for you to know that i created an app using the usual approach and i can still start my devserver using npm start

Comment: Have you checked the content of the log file indicated in the console? Can you share its content in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to the challenge i had before now. follow these steps

1. npm install -g yarn
2. yarn global add create-react-app
3. create-react-app